# Error processing the Azure analysis server model from SSMS

Tags: ssms, azure-analysis-services

1. Analysis server model was created using the Power BI.
2. Uploaded the model to the Azure Analysis Server.
3. Connected to the Azure Analysis Server from SSMS 2017
4. Tried to process full and got the following error.

---

**Error**

> "An M partition uses a data function which results in access to a data source 
>   different from those defined in the model"

Any help? Thank you

Comment: Can you post the M code?

Comment: Hi There was no M code.I just created the power Bi and pointed to Azure Data Lake store, before publishing it to the Azure Analysis server

Comment: Go to the power query editor, you can get there by selecting the "edit queries" option on the home ribbon on the power bi desktop. Once you are in the power query editor, right click on a table and select the "Advanced Editor" option. This will open up the advanced editor, you will find your M code here. Post a pic of the code for each table and we may be able to find a solution.